# Is there a possible way to cut the specific part of divs using HTML & CSS

Tags: html, css

Is there a way where I can achieve the same thing like this in HTML/CSS

[image]

I want to achieve this kind of crop (The Stair-Like Crop) in a div where the "My Gallery div" dodges the bottom of "Music div". I've done the overlaying techniques such as creating a new div (and use clip path) and float it on right but it just blocks the end List of music.

Comment: you should edit your question and add your code and the problem you got, this is the better way to get help here.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the overflow tag in css.

```css
.container {
  background: #999;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  z-index:999;
  padding: 10px;
}

.list-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.list {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.song {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #bbb;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Arial;
  display: block;
}

.song:hover {
  background: #888;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='list-container'>
    <table class='list'>
      <td class='song'>
        <span>Song 1.</span>
      </td>
      <td class='song'>
        <span>Song 2.</span>
      </td>
      <td class='song'>
        <span>Song 3.</span>
      </td>
      <td class='song'>
        <span>Song 4.</span>
      </td>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```